# Replaceing the content of a div funtion which also is changing class

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div class="button button1" id="content" onclick="toggleClass(event);">Stay Updated</div>
```

```js
<script>
    function toggleClass(evt) {
        var btn = evt.target;

        if (btn.className == "button button1") {
            btn.className = "info";
            btn.onclick = null;
        } else {
            btn.className = "button button1";
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

Trying to change the content of the div after the click has happened and during the change in class.

---

Comment: When you say you're trying to do this, what does that mean? I don't see any code that looks like an attempt to change the content.

Comment: And is there a reason you're removing the `onclick` handler? It looks like the function is meant to toggle. Does the handler get restored elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try creating a text node using `document.createTextNode` which will take care of character escaping as well.

```js
function toggleClass(event) { 
   var btn = evt.target;
   //Clears the div
    while(btn.firstChild){
        btn.removeChild(btn.firstChild);
    }

    if (btn.className == "button button1") {
        btn.className = "info";
        btn.onclick = null;
        
        //Append hello to the div
        btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('World'));
    } else {
        btn.className = "button button1";
        btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'));
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="button button1" id="content" onclick="toggleClass(event);">Stay Updated</div>
```